# About the Java Client Call the WCF

Tags: c#, java, wcf

I have a Java Client that calls a web service written in Csharp  by the axis. 
And now, I want to change the webservice to the wcf(net tcp ..) . 
But , I dont know what I can do with the Java Client. 
Is Anybody can give me some ideas about it ? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WCF, but only with simpleHttpBinding.

SimpleHttpBinding conforms to the WS-I Basic Profile 1.1, and can therefore interact with components written using other technologies (in your case, Java)

However, NetTcpBinding does not conform to any public protocol, so its use is limited to communication between .NET components.